# how to apply shared element animation in ViewPager fragments?

Tags: android, animation, android-design-library, shared-element-transition

I want to animate a view with SharedElement transition from one Fragment to another fragment in ViewPager.

I've 3 fragments in a ViewPager, each fragment is having a single TextView with same transition name in XML file.

Now, when ViewPager slides another Fragment, I want to see SharedElement in action.

Comment: Hi rahul use this link for shared element transition in fragments  https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/

Comment: Thanks @Jinu, I've tried this as well. But its not fulfilling my concern. 
I want to animate view in Fragments using ViewPager. Inside FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: shared element transitions are not available to virewpager but you can transfrom elements like flickr https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.nubwfyiog

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay Have u got any solution for this?

Comment: @Shubham, not yet. Not the exact way I wanted to with View Pager but we can do with Fragments same as Activity Transition.
Please refer https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had the same issue. Standard shared element transitions are not working between ViewPager pages.

So I wrote a [Shared Element View Pager](https://github.com/kirillgerasimov/Shared-Element-View-Pager) library. It works both for transitions caused by onClick() events (such as viewPager.setCurrentItem(x) ) and page slides caused by user. The animation is bound to finger movement.

It's not an android transition so there could be some obstacles. Take a look though.

[SharedElementPageTransformer demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymgHt.gif)

#### Usage

1. Add all fragments from your ViewPager to the List in the same order.

```
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(hello_fragment);
        fragments.add(small_picture_fragment);
```

2. Create *SharedElementPageTransformer* presumably in *Activity.onCreate()*. 
   *this* refers to activity:

```
        SharedElementPageTransformer transformer =
                new SharedElementPageTransformer(this,  fragments);
```

3. Add shared transition by passing pairs of view ids, that need to be linked together

```
        transformer.addSharedTransition(R.id.smallPic_image_cat, R.id.bigPic_image_cat);
```

4. Set our *transformer* to ViewPager's pageTransformer **AND** onPageChangeListener.

```
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, transformer);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(transformer);
```

Answer (score -1):

it's been maybe a too long time but could be helpful though.
It's totally possible to have shared elements transitions between 2 viewPagers since i already did it myself.

I think the thing you are maybe missing is **that transition name has to be unique !**
So it has to be set programmatically and not in XML ! It's very important in ViewPager since same view could be inflated many times.

```
imageView.setTransitionName("unique_name");
```

This way the transition knows on what element it should be played;)

Comment: can u elaborate your answer?